# Max message size in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-rest-proxy

I use **Apache Kafka**, **Zookeeper**, **Confluent REST Proxy** and **Web UI**. I am sending a 5mb message, but it does not appear in the Web UI, nor does it appear in the topic as a whole (I do not receive a message when I try to read the topic).

I found out that Kafka has a 1mb limit per message by default, and that the `message.max.bytes` parameter is responsible for this limit. I added a string to `server.properties` in which I set the value of this parameter to 20mb (in bytes), also I added `replica.fetch.max.bytes`. And I added `max.request.size` and `max.partition.fetch.bytes` to the producer and consumer properties files. Then I restarted the server. However, this did not help. How can I increase the size of received and sent messages?